# Share scope between Angular Bootstrap Modal and parent Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I want to show a modal in one of my controllers, and have that modal share the same scope as that controller so that it can modify data of that original scope.  I tried doing something like this:

```
        $scope.modalInstance=$modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'some_template.tmpl.html',
            scope:$scope

        });
```

But when I bind to properties of that scope from within the modal, they don't change.  It can read them though.  I don't want to use a result promise.

Comment: look here https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ how this should be done - u pass object and get object when modal is closed

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to resolve data (which you should be doing), you can create a service which holds your data and `$inject` it in both your parent controller and the modal controller.